# Migrated from ASP.NET Core 1.1 to 2.0. Fails with "Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80004005"

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I've updated my application from ASP.NET Core v1.1 to ASP.NET Core 2.0.

Everything works fine on my dev machine. But when I'm deploying to Azure I get `"HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure"` as a response.

I've activated logging in web.config:

```
<aspNetCore processPath=".\PublicWeb2.Web.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```

The log says:

> Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80004005

I get the same error if I run `dotnet mysite.dll` from the command prompt in Kudo.

The event log in Azure gives the following error:

> Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/XXXXX' with physical root 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\' failed to start process with commandline 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\XXX ', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : 80008089.

Relevant Azure settings:

[image]

My complete csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>XXXXXXXXXXX</UserSecretsId>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win7-x86;win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <WebProject_DirectoryAccessLevelKey>1</WebProject_DirectoryAccessLevelKey>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MarkdownWeb" Version="1.3.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="MarkdownWeb.Git" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.NameResolution" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\XXX\XXX.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Dotnet version installed on the cloud service:

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot>dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (2.0.0)

Product Information:
 Version:            2.0.0
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  cdcd1928c9

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  6.2.9200
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win8-x86
 Base Path:   D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\


Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host
  Version  : 2.0.0
  Build    : e8b8861ac7faf042c87a5c2f9f2d04c98b69f28d
```

What I've done (from reading other SO questions):

- Added `win7-x86` as the first runtime identifier in my csproj
- Selected win7-x86 in the azure deployment settings
- Manually deleted all old files from wwwroot using the console in Kudo (and then deployed again)
- Tried with `COREHOST_TRACE=1` activated, but then the console hangs in kudo (and piping to a log doesnt work, i.e. `dotnet myapp.dll > mylog.txt`)

I have no clue about what to do next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got it working.

### 1. Remove runtime identifiers in your project file

In the csproj file of the webproject I removed the `<RuntimeIdentifiers>` element (it's `<RuntimeIdentifier>` if you've specified a single runtime).

### 2. Remove `<RuntimeIdentifier>` in the publish profile.

The pubxml can be found in solution explorer under

```
Project -> Properties -> PublishProfiles -> yourfilename.pubxml.
```

Remove the following line (which got your runtime specified)

```
<RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

Save the file and close it.

Next time you run the publish command, it should say "portable" under the `Settings` option:

[image]

That worked for me.

Thus my guess is that the real solution is:

1. Stop the site in the azure portal
2. Remove all old files from the "wwwroot" folder using kudo: https://YOURSITE.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole, run "rmdir /q /s ." in the wwwroot folder.
3. Make sure that no `RuntimeIdentifier` is specified in the publish profile
4. Make sure that no `RuntimeIdentifier` is specified in the csproj file
5. Publish the site
6. Start the site in the azure portal